# "Selector loop waiting on select" when running multiple test cases which use wiremock stubs

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, wiremock

I'm using [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) for mocking a web service. I'm using that to provide a service access to some of units that we are testing. So basically we have multiple junit tests which use stubs from wiremock.

But when we run multiple tests at once (let's say run a whole test.java file) it will keep waiting after it completed some of the test cases. And something like following will be displayed at the bottom of the log,

```
[qtp1669854350-14-selector-ServerConnectorManager@62dfb098/0]
 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager - Selector loop waiting on select
```

Junit version : 4.12 
Wiremock version : 2.5.0 (wiremock-standalone) 
Java version : 1.8.0_77

Also I checked [this SO problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055440/jettyjersey-infinite-loop-with-curl-post-query). But still can't figure out how to overcome this.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @Andrew no I was not able to solve this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

That message is probably a red herring. I suggest grabbing a thread dump during a pause (kill -3  on *nix). That will tell you where exactly the code is blocking.