# Enable Geode REST to use HTTP and HTTPS at the same time

Tags: gemfire, geode

If we set Geode properties to [use ssl for web](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/10/managing/security/implementing_ssl.html) then that means we have to use HTTPS for all web traffic. Is there a way to configure Geode, for development purposes, to use both HTTP on 1 port (8080) but also HTTPS on another (8443) ?

It looks like [Jetty can be configured](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169760/1964277) to allow both using multiple connectors, [even on the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24891007/1964277)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that isn't possible at the moment. I'd suggest trying to start different instances of the various components (locator and server) with different SSL settings (off or on) for testing purposes.